# Full Hyperlink path in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I've got a column in an Excel file, and in it I have only values like 'ReleaseDoc' but they are all hyperlinks to something like this:

```
\\server1\folder1\subFolderA\subFolderB\SubFolderC\RealseaseDoc.doc
```

Now, what I want to do is to have in another column the path for the file, extracted from the hyperlink, and I've done that with this macro function

```
Function HLink(rng As Range) As String
If rng(1).Hyperlinks.Count Then HLink = rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function
```

in each cell I call this function with the appropriate cell from where I want to extract the address

The problem is that what I get displayed is something like this:

```
../../../SubFolderB/SubFolderC/RealeasesDoc.doc
```

I don't see the full path to the docs, can anyone help with this vba function?

PS: I've already searched the posts and found nothing like this

Thank you

Comment: could not reproduce the issue, i get the actual path in full. what is the address you get when CTRL+K?

Comment: @AndreiDoanca .. already tried in local Hyperlink and it worked .. where did you display the result ?

Answer (score 7):

Excel will change the address to a relative address whenever it can. To prevent this, you need to set the Hyperlink Base property. In Excel 2010, click File - Info, Show More Properties if necessary, and enter a Hyperlink Base of C:.

If there is no Hyperlink Base, it's assumed to be the path of the workbook. By setting it to C:, you force Excel to show you the whole path because it can't create a path relative to C:.  If you make your Hyperlink Base \server\folder1\, you will get a relative path because Excel *can* make a path relative to that.

So if you want to guarantee full paths in Address, make the Hyperlink Base property a different share than the workbook or a different local drive than the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is indicated here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/903163/how-to-create-absolute-hyperlinks-and-relative-hyperlinks-in-word-documents

The link drives to MSWord support page however it works also for MSExcel (I verified it with MSExcel2010). Shortly two solutions are presented: the first applies to all documents while the second applies to a single document.